# Configrue Exim Sendmail for relay

Tags: php, centos, sendmail, exim

I have a VPS server at UltraHosting.com and requires that I use "Smart Relay" when sendning emails. However I cannot send mail using the php mail() function.

Here is an article they have on Smart Relay: support.ultrahosting.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=142

The setting shown there is in my Exim config.

I have also tried configure my sendmail as suggested here http://support.ultrahosting.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=175&nav=0

However I cannot find my sendmail.cg on my centOS server. The command "whereis sendmail.cf" says *sendmail: /usr/sbin/sendmail /usr/lib/sendmail*

The server is using cpanel and exim

**I sent the following support ticket**:

> How do I configure the server to
>   send mail using php. I am writting a
>   script that will send the users
>   passwsord usigng PHPs mail function.
>   However the emails sent are never
>   delivered. Does this have to do with
>   "smart relay"? Any guide on how to
>   configure this?

Response was:

> ```
> While we do not provide scripting support of any kind, if you simply
> ```
>
> ensure the smart host is hard coded in
>   your script (no authentication is
>   necessary) the email should be
>   forwarded accordingly.
>
> ```
> If your script uses the server's SMTP server to send out email, you'll
> ```
>
> have to ensure the MTA is configured
>   to use the smart host

.

Could anyone please clarify what I need to do in order to fix this so I can use PHPs mail function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the routers section of your exim config, you'll have a router that looks something like this:

```
 lookuphost:
    driver = lookuphost
    transport = remote_smtp
```

This is what tells exim to deliver mail directly.  You need to tell it to use the smarthost instead.

Replace the above router with something like this:

```
 smarthost:
   driver = manualroute
   domains= ! +local_domains
   transport = remote_smtp 
   route_list = *  smtp.ultrahosting.com  byname
   host_find_failed = defer
   no_more
```

Make sure that the transport name in the new router is the same as in the original (remote_smtp in this example).

Also, you'll need to restart exim after making these changes.

Comment: Thanks, made a fresh config and added code. Now my maillog says: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address, when sending to an gmail account. But I suppose thats another issue